# How to interpret DataFrame[approx_count_distinct(salary): bigint]?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am simultaneously spinning up on Python and Spark via PySpark by
following [this
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-aggregate-functions).
Here is the minimum working example:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[10]").appName("SparkExamples.com").getOrCreate()
>>> simpleData = [ ("James", "Sales", 3000),
                   ("Michael", "Sales", 4600),
                   ("Robert", "Sales", 4100),
                   ("Maria", "Finance", 3000),
                   ("James", "Sales", 3000),
                   ("Scott", "Finance", 3300),
                   ("Jen", "Finance", 3900),
                   ("Jeff", "Marketing", 3000),
                   ("Kumar", "Marketing", 2000),
                   ("Saif", "Sales", 4100) ]
>>> schema = ["employee_name", "department", "salary"]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(data=simpleData, schema = schema)
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------+----------+------+
|employee_name|department|salary|
+-------------+----------+------+
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|      Michael|     Sales|  4600|
|       Robert|     Sales|  4100|
|        Maria|   Finance|  3000|
|        James|     Sales|  3000|
|        Scott|   Finance|  3300|
|          Jen|   Finance|  3900|
|         Jeff| Marketing|  3000|
|        Kumar| Marketing|  2000|
|         Saif|     Sales|  4100|
+-------------+----------+------+
```

Section "approx_count_distinct Aggregate Function" shows the
following example for counting the distinct values in a column:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import approx_count_distinct
>>> print( "approx_count_distinct: " +
           str( df.select(approx_count_distinct("salary"))
                   .collect()[0][0] ) )

approx_count_distinct: 6
```

I tried to get some insight into some of the intermediate objects
returned by the methods `approx_count_distinct`, `select`, and
`collect`:

```
>>> approx_count_distinct("salary")
Out[148]: Column<'approx_count_distinct(salary)'>

df.select(approx_count_distinct("salary"))
Out[149]: DataFrame[approx_count_distinct(salary): bigint]
```

I can guess that a scalar `bigint` is a large integer type for the
count that is being sought.  However, I'm not sure how the square
brackets are supposed to be interpreted.  Square brackets are normally
for indexing and slicing, but that doesn't make sense when the inside
is a scalar count value.  I'm not aware of any type hinting
conventions for which the above use of square brackets makes sense.

***Would it be right to conclude that this doesn't follow any convention
at all,*** and that it is just an ad hoc way to say that result is new
object of class `DataFrame` with a single cell containing the large
integer value representing the count of distinct values of `df.salary`?
That's what the following seems to show, but I want to be sure that
I'm not ignorant of a specific convention that I should become
familiar with, which can help my navigation of the documentation:

```
>>> df.select(approx_count_distinct("salary")).show()
+-----------------------------+
|approx_count_distinct(salary)|
+-----------------------------+
|                            6|
+-----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square brackets in the representation `DataFrame[approx_count_distinct(salary): bigint]` aren't denoting indexing or slicing, as they would in Python lists, nor are they type hints in the conventional Python sense. They're actually part of the string representation of a PySpark DataFrame object to provide a schema-like summary.

In PySpark, when you execute `df.select(approx_count_distinct("salary"))`, it returns a new DataFrame.
This DataFrame has a single column whose type is bigint. The column itself is the result of the
approx_count_distinct("salary") function applied to the original DataFrame (df).

The square brackets in this context are meant to give you an idea of what the DataFrame's structure looks like,
specifically in terms of its columns and their types.  *It's essentially a way to summarize the schema of the DataFrame
succinctly* which is crucial information when you're building a Spark query.

Comment: Thanks, @mamonu. Could you please confirm something?  String representations are generated using `str()` and `repr()`, the 1st being user-friendly and the 2nd being rigorous, ideally a Python expression that can recreate the object (from my web wanderings). When you say "square brackets...give you an idea of...", it sounds the use of brackets in colloquial writing, which puts it in the `str()` camp rather than `repr()`.  Does this mean that there is no Spark-specific convention that I should spin up on in order to better navigate the documentation?

Comment: The square brackets in Spark's query plan output are generally there for human readability and to provide contextual information. They're not intended to be parsed programmatically to recreate an object or query plan, so in that sense, you could say they're more aligned with the `str()` philosophy. One thing i would advise is to also try to look at the source code on functions you are interested in. Spark documentation makes that easy as there is always a link to the relevant source code file.